# debezium interrupted while locking table/schema error when application starts

Tags: sql-server, debezium

```
2022-04-03 13:51:05.343  INFO 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] .d.r.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource : Snapshot step 3 - Locking captured tables [dbo.Users]
2022-04-03 13:51:05.343  INFO 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] d.c.s.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource : Setting locking timeout to 10 s
2022-04-03 13:51:05.344 DEBUG 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerStatement:3 created by (ConnectionID:2 ClientConnectionId: 4c2ec870-bbb3-4770-b4de-d72207e50092)
2022-04-03 13:51:05.344 TRACE 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection          : executing 'SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10000'
2022-04-03 13:51:05.344 DEBUG 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerStatement:3 Executing (not server cursor) SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10000
2022-04-03 13:51:05.350  INFO 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] d.c.s.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource : Executing schema locking
2022-04-03 13:51:05.350 DEBUG 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerStatement:4 created by (ConnectionID:2 ClientConnectionId: 4c2ec870-bbb3-4770-b4de-d72207e50092)
2022-04-03 13:51:05.352  WARN 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] .d.p.s.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource : Snapshot was interrupted before completion
2022-04-03 13:51:05.352  INFO 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] .d.p.s.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource : Snapshot - Final stage
2022-04-03 13:51:05.353  INFO 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] d.c.s.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource : Removing locking timeout
2022-04-03 13:51:05.353 DEBUG 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerStatement:5 created by (ConnectionID:2 ClientConnectionId: 4c2ec870-bbb3-4770-b4de-d72207e50092)
2022-04-03 13:51:05.353 TRACE 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection          : executing 'SET LOCK_TIMEOUT -1'
2022-04-03 13:51:05.353 DEBUG 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerStatement:5 Executing (not server cursor) SET LOCK_TIMEOUT -1
2022-04-03 13:51:05.356  WARN 14190 --- [rce-coordinator] i.d.p.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator       : Change event source executor was interrupted
java.lang.InterruptedException: Interrupted while locking table dbo.Users
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource.lockTablesForSchemaSnapshot(SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:135) ~[debezium-connector-sqlserver-1.8.1.Final.jar!/:1.8.1.Final]
    at io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.doExecute(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:106) ~[debezium-core-1.8.1.Final.jar!/:1.8.1.Final]
    at io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:76) ~[debezium-core-1.8.1.Final.jar!/:1.8.1.Final]
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.doSnapshot(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:153) ~[debezium-core-1.8.1.Final.jar!/:1.8.1.Final]
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(SqlServerChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:69) ~[debezium-connector-sqlserver-1.8.1.Final.jar!/:1.8.1.Final]
```

anyone had this issue? I got this during application startup. I assume it's a missing configuration on the database. but when i ran profiler, i dont errors. Is it suggesting debezium cannot obtain a lock?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there be some code after submitting the engine to an ExecutorService. For example,

```
// Run the engine asynchronously ...
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(engine);

// Do something else or wait for a signal or an event

// YOU CAN WAITING FOREVER
while (!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
}
```